# How can i write a stored procedure which will perform a calculation and store the result in a table?

Tags: innodb, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `siteArea` (
  `length` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `breadth` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `Area` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `roadArea` (
  `Area` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `roadWidth` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `roadArea` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Where

```
Area = length * breadth;
roadArea = Area * road_width;
```

The Column Area from siteArea table has to be updated into Area column of the roadArea table.

Any changes to the Area of siteArea table has to be updated to the roadArea table and roadArea has to perform the calculation automatically without input from user.

Comment: Do you have already some code? Can you make it more clear what you want? If you want to fill the field with the data in the same row then why do you need to calculate it?

Comment: i want to write the calculation of site area and road area in a procedure so that any changes to the input of the site area has to recalculate both functions and update accordingly.

Comment: You need to do this in an update trigger. For the first calculation. Which `Area`? The one in `siteArea` or the one in `roadArea`?

Comment: first siteArea is calculated.

Comment: Why do you want to store a field that you calculate with 2 fields in the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put a trigger on the siteArea table so that whenever it's updated or inserted, it'll call a stored procedure with an argument representing the new site area and that procedure will calculate the needed values and insert them in a table.

Your question is too ambiguous for me to describe further.